# how to display multiple fields on a cell in iphone programing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm reading a record from database that has few parameters. I want to display all of them in a cell (UITableView), but I can display only one parameter.
How can I display multiple fields (parameters) on a cell?

Comment: Apple has a great guide for TableView-Programming: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS: Customizing Cells][1]. Please read it, and if then you still have (more specific) questions, come back and ask again. [1]:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18

Answer (score 0):

You can inherits from UITableViewCell make for it .xib and put any control you want: UILabel, UIButton, etc.
Make accessors for them and in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method returns instance of your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to style of the Cell to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` or `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

Then you can do something like `cell.textLabel.text = @"Main text"` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Secondary Text"`

Or as Luft-on says: make a custom Cell.